# MVC 5 how to force browser to open PDF file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I spend the whole day trying to force a browser to open PDF files instead of download it using `System.Web.Mvc.FileResult` and in the and I did it in old fashion way System.Web.Response like this:

**Contoller**

```
 //StaticData.ReportsTemp  it's my  type of Dictionary<string,object>
public async Task<ActionResult> GenerateReport() {
    //some code 
    var tempGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    StaticData.ReportsTemp[tempGuid] = File(strem, obj.MediaType, obj.name);
    return Content(opertionGuid);
}

public FileResult DownloadReport(string fileName) {
    FileResult result = null;
    FileStreamResult st = null;
    if (StaticData.ReportsTemp.ContainsKey(fileName)) {
        st = StaticData.ReportsTemp[fileName] as FileStreamResult;
        result = st;
        StaticData.ReportsTemp.Remove(fileName);
        if (st.ContentType == System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf || 1 == 1) { //Old fashion way
            byte[] buff = null;
            System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(st.FileStream);
            buff = br.ReadBytes((int) st.FileStream.Length);
            Response.BinaryWrite(buff);
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buff.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = st.ContentType;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + st.FileDownloadName + ";");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**JS**

```
function onSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
    window.open("@Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "Main", Action = "DownloadReport" })?filename=" + xhr.responseText,'_brank');
}
```

My downloading process is divided on two steps:

1. 1) I'm generation report , create FileStremResult ,saving  into
   StaticData.Reports  dictionary and return dictionary key to client
2. 2) using dictionary key recived from step 1 I'm calling action
       Download which return FileStremResult from StaticData.Reports dictionary

PDF are opened in browser and all other files still are simply just downloading.

But I'm still wondering if there is any other way to achieve this?
Is there any way to do this with System.Web.Mvc  ActionResult's classes ?

Comment: I'm not sure I want a website to be able to download a pdf(potentially containing malware), and then open it. Even if you're doing this for legitimate reasons, the ability to do this at all seems like a security issue to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how `StaticData` class work. Normally, you could return `FileResult`, and if file is not valid or doesn't exist, you could display PageNotFound page.

Note: if client doesn't have Acrobat installed, you cannot force them to view inside browser.

```
public class ReportFile
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> GenerateReport()
{
    //some code 
    var tempGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    StaticData.ReportsTemp[tempGuid] = new ReportFile
    {
        Data = data, // Convert stream to byte array
        ContentType = obj.MediaType,
        FileName = obj.name
    };
    return Content(tempGuid);
}

public ActionResult DownloadReport(string fileName)
{
    if (StaticData.ReportsTemp.ContainsKey(fileName))
    {
        ReportFile file = StaticData.ReportsTemp[fileName];
        StaticData.ReportsTemp.Remove(fileName);

        if (file.ContentType == MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf)
        {
            var cd = new ContentDisposition { FileName = file.FileName, Inline = true };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(file.Data, file.ContentType);
        }
    }
    return View("PageNotFound");
}
```

Comment: Try to do it with ContentDisposition and Response.AppendHeader  and it's not working for me .
I Update my question with more specific description

Comment: What do you return `FileStremResult`? All `FileResult` needs is a byte array.

Comment: If you would look into `GenerateReport` action you will see  method `File()`first parameter  is`stream `, second is `media Type` , and last is `file name` , there result of  this method is `FileStremResult.`  The method `File() `s method from `web.MVC` library

Comment: Do not store FileResult inside dictionary. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thx  for advice to saving object with byte array instead of FileStem  , and also thx for example which show me what was wrong in my code.
I was doing the same think that you BUT instead of returning ` File(file.Content, file.ContentType)` a was returning '  accroding to this article   [link](https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/asp-net-mvc-displaying-a-pdf-document-in-the-browser/)   ` File(file.Content, file.ContentType, file.Name) `  which  cause ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION